# Concatenating Own Strings with the Separated ArrayList

Tags: c#, string, arraylist

My ArrayList Object Contains 3 Values.

```
ArrayList arr=new ArrayList()
arr.Add("abc");
arr.Add("def");
arr.Add("ghi");
```

I've got the requirement to Separate the Values with a **,**  Separator

So, I googled and got the solution as

```
string afterjoined=string.Join(",", (string[])arr.ToArray(Type.GetType("System.String")));
```

The above code will return as

> **abc,def,ghi**

But the above code will not allow any string to be concatenated with it.

I want a Specific string that needs to be concatenated with the final, separated values like the below,

> **MYabc,MYdef,Myghi**

Here what I tried with the existing code(Which is not working)

```
string afterjoined=string.Join(",", "MYabc"+(string[])arr.ToArray(Type.GetType("System.String")));
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `ArrayList` rather than `List<string>`?

Comment: Actually, I'm developing a SSIS Package. So I've to read all the rows in my file using ArrayList

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
string.Join(",", 
    arr.Cast<string>() // use cast here instead of the casting to reduce the number of ()s
    .Select(x => "MY" + x))
```

The `Select` call transforms each of the strings in the list by doing your specified transformation. In this case, it's `"MY" + x`, so it will prefix `MY` to each of the elements in the array.

And why are you using ArrayLists? They are not type-safe. You should be using `List<T>` instead. The code will become much cleaner:

```
List<string> arr=new List<string>();
arr.Add("abc");
arr.Add("def");
arr.Add("ghi");
string joined = string.Join(",", arr.Select(x => "MY" + x));
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this extension method (normally with generic `IEnumerable`, modified for `ArrayList`) if I need that functionality:

```
    public static string MergeWithPrefix(this ArrayList list, string prefix, string separator = ";")
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(list.Count * 16);

        foreach (var item in list)
            sb.Append(prefix).Append(item).Append(separator);
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - separator.Length, separator.Length);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```